# How to set <input type="number" /> field with float step in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

i have created the number field in tinymce using following code

```
{type: 'textbox', subtype: 'number', name: 'val1', size: 5, label: 'Number Position', value: '0.4'}
```

but i need to step over the field as float . like this

```
  <input type="number" name="points" step="0.1">
```

step doesn't work in tinymce